# How do I take the latest from another branch and then do a commit

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

Pardon me as I am a newbie to git. I understand SVN and if someone can explain it in terms of SVN, that will be great. Currently, I am using the tool GitHub for Mac. But, I am open to using the terminal.

I am working locally on a master branch. A colleague has made changes in another branch. Before I checkin my changes, I want to merge that branch into my local master branch and then commit. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your colleague has pushed his changes to the central repository, you could do this

```
git fetch
```

Git fetch will get your colleagues changes to your local repository.

Let's say the branch he worked on was called `other_branch`, then you can do this to merge his changes to your current branch:

```
git merge origin/other_branch
```

When you are done merging you can push your changes to the central repository:

```
git push
```

Comment: where am I telling it to merge into my local master branch?

Comment: @Sandbox I am assuming that you already have it checked out (if not do `git checkout master`). `git merge origin/other_branch` will merge the branch `origin/other_branch` to your current branch, i.e. local master.

Comment: just inquisitive, is there a way to do this using the github tool?

Comment: @Sandbox I am not familiar with that particular tool, but I would be surprised it it was not possible. All these operations are basic stuff, and almost all the Git GUI tools that I know can handle them.